# How to use QCalendarWidget with QDataWidgetMapper?

Tags: qt, pyside, model-view

I currently have my calendar widget mapped using QDataWidgetMapper like this (using PySide):

```
self.mapper.addMapping(self.ui.calendar, 2, "selectedDate")
```

And it does display the correct date when I do:

```
self.mapper.toFirst()
```

But my problem is that when I change the selected date clicking on a different date the mapping doesn't capture the change and save it to the database. In other words, the mapper does not issue a setData on the model or setModelData in case I choose to use a delegate.

What I am missing?

Edit: I found the solution. What I did above was right but the mapper wasn't auto submitting  the data. What I did was:

```
self.ui.calendar.selectionChanged.connect(self.ui.mapper.submit())
```

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, make it an answer instead. And you can even accept it. That is both accepted and recommended. So don't hesitate to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. What I did above was right but the mapper wasn't auto submitting the data. What I did was:

self.ui.calendar.selectionChanged.connect(self.ui.mapper.submit())